# Windows Application (C#.Net)- Retain TextBox Values

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is my Scenario: (Windows Application/C#.Net)

I have a Form1 in that is doing some calculations with the option selected as Case 1 and On Button Click it Pushes all the textbox values to Form2. This is working fine.

Now if I come to Form 1 again and change the option to case 2 and calculate and press Button it erases the values that were added earlier.

I want to retain those values and add this values to another set of textboxes that are in Form2.

Code: In Form 1 After Clicking ADD button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 eigthForm = new Form2();
        if(comboBox1.Text == "Case 1")
        {
            eigthForm.text2.Text = textBox1.Text;
            eigthForm.text3.Text = textBox8.Text;
        }   
        if (comboBox1.Text == "Case 2")
        {
            eigthForm.text4.Text = textBox1.Text;
            eigthForm.text5.Text = textBox8.Text;
        }
```

Comment: Post some code.

Comment: Hi Matt, Posted Code. Will you please have a look at code and suggest any solution. Thanks.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of Form2 each time you click the button. It won't retain the values since its a new instance. Having a global object (static) to hold all your values would be a good place to start. Exposing TextBoxes publicly like that isn't a great idea. See Tsukasa answer for some ideas around Global stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I understand what you are asking now. You can use the Singleton pattern as one way as follows

Form1 buttons

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2.Instance.AddText1and2("Hello", "World");
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2.Instance.AddText3("Foo");
}
```

Form2 we will change to Singleton pattern

```
   private static volatile Form2 instance = null;
    private static object lockThis = new object();

    private Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static Form2 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock(lockThis)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new Form2();
                    }
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
```

Now our methods to place text in the correct places

```
public void AddText1and2(string txt1, string txt2)
    {
        textBox1.Text = txt1;
        textBox2.Text = txt2;
        this.Show();
    }

    public void AddText3(string txt3)
    {
        textBox3.Text = txt3;
        this.Show();
    }
```

If you want to be able to close the window and reopen it saving values you need to use the form closing event

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

You have to prevent the actual close. This will dispose the object and we don't want that.

This will keep all your settings in form 2.

---

if you don't want to do the above you can add a new class to your project doing something like this

```
class Global
{
    public static string Value1 { get; set; }
    public static string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

in Form1

```
if(comboBox1.Text == "Case 1")
{
        Global.Value1 = textBox1.Text;
        Global.Value2 = textBox8.Text;
}
```

in Form2 load event

```
text2.Text = Global.Value1;
text3.Text = Global.Value2;
```

---

You should also revise your if logic
The combobox will never == "Case 2" if it's "Case 1" but you
Are still running the next if statement

You should use something like this

```
if(comboBox1.Text.Equals("Case 1"))
{
}
else if (comboBox1.Text.Equals("Case 2"))
{
}
```

OR

```
switch (comboBox1.Text)
{
    case "Case 1":
        //do stuff
    break;
    case "Case 2":
        //do stuff
    break;
}
```

Comment: Hi Tsukasa, Will you please suggest example as per my code above. How should I proceed with Global stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Tsukasa, I am trying your solution. Will check and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is on Case 1 and Submit will push all the values to Form2. Then I come back to Form 2 and select Case 2 and do some calculation and Submit again and this time the first submitted value should be ther in Form 2 and now submitted values should also be there in new textboxes.

Comment: You enter values on form1 click a button that pushes them to form2. You will see form2 display with values, then you go back to form one, do some other logic and push those to form2 in other text boxes. The above 2 solutions will do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a Ton Tsukasa, the solution you gave worked like a Charm.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option

```
Form2 inst = null;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(inst == null)
           inst = new Form2();


        if(comboBox1.Text == "Case 1")
        {
            inst.text2.Text = textBox1.Text;
            inst.text3.Text = textBox8.Text;
        }   
        if (comboBox1.Text == "Case 2")
        {
            inst.text4.Text = textBox1.Text;
            inst.text5.Text = textBox8.Text;
        }

 inst.Show();

}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the prompt reply I will implement now and Mark the answer as soon as it works. Thanks again.

Comment: By default, the controls on Form2 will be private.  The modifiers would have to be updated in order to access them directly like in your example.

Comment: You have to add an event handler for the FormClosed event so you can reset inst back to null.  Required or the program will crash with ObjectDisposedException when Form2 is closed and the is button pressed again.  And to allow the Form2 object to get garbage collected.

Comment: Hi Matt, Tried the solution you gave but it shows error as inst does not exist in the current context.