# Use objects of different forms c#

Tags: c#, forms, object

I'm trying to make a simple text editor for a homework. I created the form with a textbox inside, where i put the text when I open a txt file, and there are 3 buttons. The first to open a file, the second to save the modifications you make in the textbox and then I'm starting to add a third button wich allows me to create a new file. So I start checking if the textbox is empty or not. If it isn't I wanna open a second form wich allows me to save what's in the textbox. The second form also has 3 buttons, the first to save, the second one to not save and the third to cancel. 
Here's the code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1(){
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void apri_file_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){
                System.IO.StreamReader input = new
                System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                TextBox_stampa_contenuto.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName); 
                input.Close();
            }
        }

        private void salva_file_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK){
                string name = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                File.WriteAllText(name, TextBox_stampa_contenuto.Text);
            }
        }

        private void nuovo_file_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (TextBox_stampa_contenuto.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
            {
                Form2 Salva = new Form2();
                Salva.Show();
            }
        }
    }

}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void salva_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string name = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                File.WriteAllText(name, TextBox_stampa_contenuto.Text);
            }
        }

        private void non_salvare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox_stampa_contenuto.Clear();
        }

        private void annulla_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The question is how I can acces the textbox or the savefiledialog of the first form from the second one.
Thanks!

Comment: The form is an object like any other object. How would you answer the question: "how can i access my first object from the second"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Don't have the second form save the data, but only return the result (YES, NO, CANCEL). Then save in the first form if so desired. (You wouldn't even need to create a second Form, you can use MessageBox for that.)
2. Give your second form a function that accepts a TextBox. The following is kind of pseudo code. I don't know the correct syntax by heart:

   public void ShowDialog(TextBox textBox)
   {
     if(ShowDialog.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes)
     {
       // save textBox content
     }
   }

Comment: I'll try using the first option! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Singleton Pattern, Pass it to Form2, Store it in a global var that can be accessed.

See me response to this post

[Windows Application (C#.Net)- Retain TextBox Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467547/windows-application-c-net-retain-textbox-values/21467659#21467659)

Answer (score 0):

Add two public property to your first `Form`:

```
public SaveFileDialog SaveDialog { get { return this.saveFileDialog1; } }

public TextBox TextBox1 { get { return this.textBox1; } }
```

Then you just need to pass your current form instance to `ShowDialog` method when you opening your second Form.

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.ShowDialog(this);
```

After that you can access your First form from second form with `Owner` property.All you need to do is cast it to Form1 so you can access your `SaveDialog`, `TextBox1` properties.For example in `Form2` you can do:

```
var txtBox = ((Form1)Owner).TextBox1;
```

Ofcourse this is one of the possible ways to do this.Another option would be adding a new constructor to `Form2` that takes some (necessary) parameters and then use that constructor when creating your `Form2` instance.